# Determine what is the screen width of the browser

Tags: javascript, width, screen

I have searched on Google for this problem but still I didn't found a solution. So basically I want to remove a class name on a specific screen width. I have a code that is working great but there is an issue with it, I am going to give an example of what is the problem. In the code I have set that when the page reach 850px it will remove the class name and it works perfectly but when I refresh the page for example on 500px it will not remove the class name, when I start to resize the page then it will remove the class name. So what I want is when I refresh the page on 500px it will remove the class name

Is there any way where I can fix this?

Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
        if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 850px)").matches){
            var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
            poster.classList.remove('fade')

            var bgtariler = document.getElementById('bg-trailer');
            bgtariler.classList.remove('fade')

            var mutebt = document.getElementById('muted-button');
            mutebt.classList.remove('fade') 
        }
        else if(video.ended){
            document.getElementById('bg-trailer').addEventListener('ended', function(){
                var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
                poster.classList.remove('fade')

                var bgtariler = document.getElementById('bg-trailer');
                bgtariler.classList.remove('fade')

                var mutebt = document.getElementById('muted-button');
                mutebt.classList.remove('fade')
            },false);
        }
        else{
            var poster = document.getElementById('poster');
            poster.classList.add('fade')

            var bgtariler = document.getElementById('bg-trailer');
            bgtariler.classList.add('fade')

            var mutebt = document.getElementById('muted-button');
            mutebt.classList.add('fade') 
        }
    })
```

Comment: Adding event listener like `onended` should be done only once, and not with every `onresize` event, and if you want the same behaviour of resizing when you refresh the page, you can assign the event listener function to both `onresize` and `onload`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reuse the very same function in the `load` event, it would be something like this

```
function handleFadeClass() {
  /* Your function */
}

window.addEventListener('load', handleFadeClass);
window.addEventListener('resize', handleFadeClass);
```